# Debug a Python program which seems paused for no reason

Tags: python, debugging

I am writing a `Python` program to analyze log files. So basically I have about 30000 medium-size log files and my `Python` script is designed to perform some simple (line-by-line) analysis of each log file. Roughly it takes less than 5 seconds to process one file.

So once I set up the processing, I just left it there and after about 14 hours when I came back, my `Python` script simply paused right after analyzing one log file; seems that it hasn't written into the file system for the analyzing output of this file, and that's it. No more proceeding.

I checked the memory usage, it seems fine (less than 1G), I also tried to write to the file system (`touch test`), it also works as normal. So my question is that, how should I proceed to debug the issue? Could anyone share some thoughts on that? I hope this is not too general. Thanks.

Comment: Does it get stuck quickly? You can load it in pdb and see what happens.

Comment: @cha0site  No it isn't. I see that over 20000 log files have been proceeded and the corresponding analysis output of each log seems normal to me.

Comment: It would help immensely if you posted the code. Do you mean the program hung after just one file, or on one particular file? Copious trace messages would obviously be the easiest way to track things down, but at a wild guess, perhaps you forget to close files and run out of file handles, and whatever error handling gets confused by that situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use [Trace or track Python statement execution](https://docs.python.org/2/library/trace.html) and/or [The Python Debugger](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) module.

Answer (score 1):

Try this tool https://github.com/khamidou/lptrace with command:

```
sudo python lptrace -p <process_id>
```

It will print every python function your program invokes and may help you understand where your program stucks or in an infinity loop.

If it does not output anything, that's proberbly your program get stucks, so try

```
pstack <process_id>
```

to check the stack trace and find out where stucks. The output of *pstack* is c frames, but I believe somehow you can find something useful to solve your problem.